# jQuery mobile and iscroll refresh

Tags: jquery, mobile, iscroll

I have a small problem with iscroll. I'm building a small app for iphone with phonegap and jquery mobile, with external data taken from json, use iscroll and data-iscroll = "", when I load the contents of the list view, iscroll works great, but if I go out and return in another article, iscroll remember the position, and I wish I could do from the top of the page.

Thi is my example http://www.viaggiosullaluna.it/es.zip

Ty for Help.

Answer (score 3):

iScroll4 has the `.refresh()` method.

considering you used something like this to create your iscroll instance:

```
var myScroll = new iScroll('idOfElement', {/*options*/});
```

Add the following at the end of the function which calls the new article (and on every function which changes the scrollable content):

```
setTimeout(function () {
    myScroll.refresh();
}, 100);
```

This way it will recalculate the height of the scrollable area and redo the scroll.
For more info, see `MASTERING THE REFRESH() METHOD` at http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

**Update**

To scroll back to top, use the following:

```
myScroll.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

The doc states `scrollTo(x, y, time, relative)`. `time` in ms (for the 'animation' of scrolling, which probably you don't want) and `relative` meant for scrolling based on current element (which you don't want also).

For more info, see `JAVASCRIPT SCROLLING` at http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my problem is different, I try to explain my problem, iscroll works on the inside pages, but if I press back and return to a page under the other, iscroll is placed in the same position you left and I want it to start the beginning of the page

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I do not understand very well. are not an ace with js unfortunately. I should understand how to insert the function myScroll.scrollTo (0, 0) in my code. You're really kind to help me. I use these three functions:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$("#malattie_page").live("pageinit", function() {
});
$("#malattie_interno_page").live("pageinit", function() {
});

$("#malattie_page").live("pagebeforeshow", function(event,data) {
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.viaggiosullaluna.it/ipediatria_admin/json/malattie.php",    
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain : true,
    async:false,
    success: function(retval, textStatus){              
        var html = "<ul id='lista_malattie' data-role='listview'  data-autodividers='true' data-filter='true' data-filter-placeholder='Search...'>";
        for (var i=0; i<retval.length; i++) {
            html += "<li><a href='#malattie_interno_page'  data-transition='slide' class='contentLink' data-entryid='"+retval[i]['id']+"' >"+retval[i] ['title']+"</a></li>";
        }
        html += "</ul>";
        $("#interno_malattie").html(html);
        $("#lista_malattie").listview();
    }
});
 });
$("#malattie_interno_page").live("pagebeforeshow", function(event,data) {
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.viaggiosullaluna.it/ipediatria_admin  /json/malattie.php?id="+selectedEntry,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain : true,
    async:false,
    success: function(retval, textStatus){    
        var html =""
        for (var i=0; i<retval.length; i++) {
            if(selectedEntry == retval[i]['id']) {
                html += "<h3>"+retval[i]['title']+"</h3>";
                html += "<div class='interno'>"+retval[i]['content']+" </div>";
             }
         }
        $("#interno_malattie_page").html(html);
    }
  });   
  });

  $("#malattie_page").live("pageshow", function(prepage) {
});
$("#malattie_interno_page").live("pageshow", function(prepage) {
setTimeout(function(){$('#malattie_interno_page [data- role="content"]').iscrollview('refresh');}, 0);
 });
```

**AND HTML**

```
<!-- PAGE MALATTIE -->
    <div data-role="page" class="ui-responsive-panel" id="malattie_page">
        <div data-role="header"  data-theme="f" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>MALATTIE</h1>
            <a href="#nav-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a></div><!-- /header -->
        <div data-role="content"  data-iscroll="">
            <div id="interno_malattie">

            </div>
        </div><!-- /content -->         

        <div data-role="panel" data-position="left" data-position-fixed="false" data-display="reveal" id="nav-panel" data-theme="a">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a" data-divider-theme="a" style="margin-top:-16px;" class="nav-search">
                <li data-icon="delete" class="close-button"><a href="#" data-rel="close">MENU INTERNO</a></li>

                <li><a href="#malattie_page" data-transition="fade">PAGE</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /panel -->           
    </div><!-- /page -->


    <!-- PAGE MALATTIE INTERNO PAGINA -->
    <div data-role="page" class="ui-responsive-panel" id="malattie_interno_page">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="f"  data-position="fixed">
            <h1>MALATTIE</h1>
            <a href="#malattie_page" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
        </div><!-- /header -->
        <div data-role="content" data-iscroll="">
            <div id="interno_malattie_page">


            </div>
        </div><!-- /content -->         

        <div data-role="panel" data-position="left" data-position-fixed="false" data-display="reveal" id="nav-panel" data-theme="a">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a" data-divider-theme="a" style="margin-top:-16px;" class="nav-search">
                <li data-icon="delete" class="close-button"><a href="#" data-rel="close">MENU INTERNO</a></li>

                <li><a href="#malattie_page" data-transition="fade">PAGE</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div><!-- /panel -->           
    </div><!-- /page -->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using iscrollview means just try this...

**1.refresh**

```
$('#videotagisc').iscrollview("refresh");
```

**2.scrollTo**

```
 $('#videotagisc').iscrollview('scrollTo', 0,0);
```